# Assign custom name for i2c-dev userspace driver in Linux?

Tags: embedded-linux, i2c, device-tree

Can I assign a custom name for an I2C bus in i2c-dev userspace driver in Linux?

In generally, Linux assigns `/dev/i2c-X` name for all I2C bus just with a incremented postfix number. Is it possible to somehow use a custom name like `/dev/my-i2c-bus0`?

Does device-tree has any similar working solution for it?

```
&i2c1 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c1>;
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    status = "okay";

    dev-name = "my-i2c-bus0";
};
```

Comment: `udev` will do it for you as a symbolic link, no need to have a kernel or device tree to modify.

Comment: Symbolic link is not fine, i need a solution based on device-tree with a label or "nickname" for specific i2c node properties, because if i have many `/dev/i2c-X`, i do not have information about what is what in real HW implementation.

Comment: You need to learn what `udev` is and how it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try using 'aliases' in your dts:

```
aliases {
    my-i2c-bus0 = &i2c1;
}
```

I suppose that this should solve your problem.

Comment: Not this is the question. I like to give a custom name in dtsi to use it in dev folder like: `/dev/my-i2c-bus0`